# ASP.NET Core is using non-default constructor if no public default constructor found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations, model-binding

I am writing ASP.NET Core 2.2.0 application hosted on Service Fabric.

I have a class which represents a request and I have declared two constructors: public for my own usage and private for serializers:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClass() // for serializer
    {
    }

    public MyClass(string myProperty) // for myself
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myProperty));
    }

    [Required]
    public string MyProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

Then, I created an API controller:

```
[ApiController]
public class MyController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] MyClass model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Doesn't matter in this example");
    }
}
```

And I test it by calling with `null` value with Fiddler:

```
PUT /MyController (Content-Type: application/json)
{
    "MyProperty": null
}
```

**The problem** I encounter is that my public constructor is called with myProperty equal to `null`, which causes `ArgumentNullException` to be thrown and results into 500 Internal Server Error.

**What I expected** is that it will use private parameterless constructor and private setters. Then, since the controller is marked with `ApiController` attribute, this model will be validated automatically against data annotations and will result into 400 Bad Request, because `MyProperty` is required.

What is interesting - if I make the default constructor public, then it works as expected, but I wouldn't want to do this.

Why doesn't it use private constructor and how can I make it use it without marking it as public?

Another question is does model binder understand how to use constructor with parameters using reflection?

Comment: Why do you assume it uses the private constructor first? My assumption would be that it calls a public one if it exists, then looks for a private constructor. I would however suggest that you are using this class for too many things. Maybe you need a different class.

Comment: You haven't told the serializer (JSON.NET) that you want it to use the default constructor, so it uses the one that best matches the input JSON

Comment: In fact, why are there *two* constructors? Are you trying to use the same class for different purposes, ie both as a REST payload and a model class for some other job? That can cause a *lot* of problems as the concerns and restrictions of a REST API are *very* different from those of a Domain class, an ORM DTO or a class used to communicate with other services.

Comment: Obligatory ["remember, when designing your WebAPI, your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model"](https://codeopinion.com/web-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model/)

Comment: @IanKemp the reasons would be using the same class to handle multiple roles. We've all fallen into that hole - eg trying to use the same "entity" class in a desktop application when creating *and* editing a record. And finding out that the hard way we can't handle the validation and business rules in both scenarios with just one class without adding quite a bit of ugly code.

Comment: @DavidG I assumed this, because this is how it works for `XmlSerializer`. You are right about using the class for too many purposes, I used two constructor in the class as a minimal example which reproduces the problem. Another comment has suggested that Json.NET serializer is being used in ASP.NET Core, I didn't know that. Seems like marking my private constructor with `[JsonConstructor]` resolves my problem :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right about using the class for too many purposes, I used two constructor in the class as a minimal example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, your comment about JSON.NET serializer gave me an insight to read about JSON.NET serilizer. I didn't know that it is being used in ASP.NET Core. After all, marking private constructor with `[JsonConstructor]` seems to be working!

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I suspect there are some *painful* reasons behind it. Using the same DTO in different scenarios is a mistake we all did. But finding out eg your team leader insists on using a *separate* constructor for unit testing and a *separate* one for production code, resulting in useless tests ... that's Jameson time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for all the feedback. Please, see my own answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56077992/3218692

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev You are right about my comment, I was in a bad mood due to something unrelated, and I apologise and have removed it. This question and answer are actually very relevant because I too had no idea that JSON.NET will use a parameterised constructor for deserializing! So I've learned something today, and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos for pointing out that Json.NET serializer is used in ASP.NET Core.
This led me to [`ConstructorHandling` setting in the Json.NET documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ConstructorHandling.htm).

### Reason of the behaviour

The documentation specifies the following:

> **ConstructionHandling.Default.** First attempt to use the public default constructor, then fall back to a single parameterized constructor, then to the non-public default constructor.

That is Json.NET searches for the constructors in the following order:

- Public default constructor
- Public parameterized constructor
- Private default constructor

And this is the reason why parameterized constructor is preferred over private default constructor.

### Use private default ctor instead of public parameterized ctor (one class)

`JsonConstructorAttribute` can be used to explicitly specify constructor to Json.NET deserializer:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyClass
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    private MyClass() // for serializer
    {
    }

    public MyClass(string myProperty) // for myself
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myProperty));
    }

    [Required]
    public string MyProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

Now Json.NET deserializer will use the explicitly specified constructor.

### Use private default ctor instead of public parameterized ctor (service)

Another way is to change `ConstructionHandling` of `JsonSerializerSettings` property to use `AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor`:

> **ConstructionHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor:** Json.NET will use a non-public default constructor before falling back to a parameterized constructor.

This is how it can be done in the `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o => {
        o.SerializerSettings.ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor;
    });
}
```

This will apply this logic to all models and the deserializer will always prefer private default constructor over public parameterized constructors for all models.

### Parameterized constructor in request model can be a code smell

In this particular example, the code has been presented to reproduce the problem.

In real code, parameterized or multiple constructors can imply that you are using classes for multiple purposes, i.e. domain model and request model. This can eventually lead to problems with reusing or supporting this code.

DTOs with public default constructor and no logic should be used for requests to avoid these problems.

Comment: Btw one reason to have parametrized model constructors would be Nullable ref types

Comment: "Parameterized constructor in request model can be a code smell" - I couldn't disagree more. Parameterless constructors are always a code smell to me. It means that an object can be constructed into an invalid state. I don't want objects that don't have the necessary fields on them, there's almost never a good reason for that.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is not logical. `private` members, including constructor are not [accessible from outside](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors).

> If a class has one or more private constructors and no public constructors, other classes (except nested classes) cannot create instances of this class.

[To bind model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#how-model-binding-works), controller has only one way - call public c-tor with every argument set to `null`.

> To make model binding possible, the class must have a public default constructor and public writable properties to bind. When model binding occurs, the class is instantiated using the public default constructor, then the properties can be set.

So to bind successfully you should:

1. Have public default c-tor
2. Have public setters for properties.

Comment: Private constructors and members is a default practice for deserialization. Deserializers are able to use them.