# Use non-default constructor for Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, mediatr

I've got an asp.net core 2.2 web application using Razor Pages and Mediatr.

My query has private setters as [described](https://jimmybogard.com/immutability-in-message-types/) in Jimmy Bogard's blog:

```
public class Query : IRequest<Result>
{
    public Query(string needle)
    {
        this.Needle = needle;
    }

    public string Needle { get; private set; }
}
```

And when i use it in my web api it's OK (even [ConstructionHandling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56076333/5752652) is noneed)

But when i use Razor Pages i'got an error 'cause there's no parameterless ctor in query:

```
public class SearchModel : PageBaseModel
{
    public SearchModel(IMediator mediator)
        : base(mediator)
    {
    }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public Accounts.Search.Query Query { get; set; }

    public Accounts.Search.Result Result { get; private set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Result = await this.Mediator.Send(Query, cancellationToken);

        return this.Page();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use private setters for model binding (without writting [custom IModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-model-binder-sample) for every query)?

Comment: Short answer: NO. Long answer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#complex-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use private setters for model binding *(without writting [custom IModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-model-binder-sample) for every query)*?

*emphasis mine*

Short answer: NO

Long answer here [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core: Complex types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#complex-types)

> ***A complex type must have a public default constructor and public writable properties to bind***. When model binding occurs, the class is instantiated using the public default constructor.

*again emphasis mine*

I believe how ever that you are mixing concerns by trying to use an immutable message request as a model for binding.